# Style password filled input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In most modern browsers, you can fill the password from stored data. And when you do that in some browsers I have noticed that the background color of the input changes. Instead of having the background color change, I have a different style in mind for that purpose.

How do I apply a style to the password field when the browser fills it?

Javascript and Jquery(not preferred), is ok to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browsers use cookies to save that kind of data for later use. They probably even give the cookie an Id event, and when that `eventId` occurs, they run some javascript/css code to change the view of the page.

You can use `addEventListener()` function and make your own configurations on how you would like to change the view and in what *exact* conditions you would like to change it.

For example:

```
//if.cookie.exists => cookieFilled()
```

You need to have knowledge of how cookies work, depending on your back-end programming language.

Javascipt function on changing the looks, configure it as you like.

```
myInput.addEventListener("cookieFilled", function(){
 myInput.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"; //background
 myInput.style.color           = "black";  // color of the text 
 console.log(myInput.type) //should return "password" if it is a password type     
}, false);
```

If you want to know more about events in javascript please see  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

You can trigger them by using `dispatchEvent()` function.

Comment: Can you show a snippet or at least a link for how I could use the `addEventListener()` function?

Comment: @Rishi here you go

Comment: Upvoted and marked as correct answer, thanks for the help!